# Placing the preposition

Tags: phrasal-verbs, transitive-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/is-it-correct-to-change-the-common-structure-in-these-phrasal-verbs)

I'm really confused about where to put the preposition.

> She cut her hair off.

Vs

> She cut off her hair.

Which one is correct? and why?

Comment: If this question is closed, I urge the mods to merge it with the question it duplicates, so @NeilCoffey's informative answer is not relegated to a dusty corner.