# Odd sounding phrasal verb splits with specific pronouns. Are there rules?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, collocation, objects, particle-shift

Give the examples...

A:

1. Did you **check** *it* **out**?
2. Did you **check** *the book* **out**?
3. Did you **check** *Netflix* **out**?
4. Did you **check** *the recommendation* **out**?
5. Did you **clean** *it* **out**?
6. Did you **wipe** *it* **off**?
7. Did you **log** *it* **in**?
8. Did you **log** *the evidence* **in**?
9. Did you **wrap** *it* **up**?
10. Did you **wrap** *the gift* **up**?
11. Did you **lock** *the house* **up**?
12. Did you **lock** *it* **up**?
13. Did you **check out** *the book*?
14. Did you **check out** *Netflix*?
15. Did you **check out** *the recommendation*?
16. Did you **log in** *the evidence*?
17. Did you **wrap up** *the gift*?
18. Did you **lock up** *the house*?

B:

1. Did you **check out** *it*?
2. Did you **clean out** *it*?
3. Did you **wipe off** *it*?
4. Did you **log in** *it*?
5. Did you **wrap up** *it*?
6. Did you **lock up** *it*?

All the above A's sound fine to me; but the B's don't.

The only pattern I see is, the sentences ending with the object *it*. But the other objects seem fine with the same usage.

Is there some rule why the B's shouldn't be used? Or are they just not common, so sound odd?

**Update:**

A:

1. Did you **back up** *the car*?
2. Did you **back up** *John*?
3. Did you **back up** *everybody*?
4. Did you **back up** *nothing*?
5. Did you **back up** *any*?
6. Did you **blow up** *balloons*?
7. Did you **help** *me* **out**?
8. Did you **help** *them* **out**?
9. Did you **wipe** *that* **off**?
10. Did you **back** *the car* **up**?
11. Did you **back** *it* **up**?
12. Did you **back** *her* **up**?
13. Did you **back** *John* **up**?
14. Did you **back** *everybody* **up**?
15. Did you **back** *nothing* **up**?
16. Did you **back** *any* **up**?
17. Did you **blow** *balloons* **up**?

B:

1. Did you **back up** *it*?
2. Did you **back up** *her*?
3. Did you **help out** *me*?
4. Did you **help out** *them*?
5. Did you **wipe off** *that*?

As I added more examples, I'm noticing this has more to do with the objects (*it*, *me*, *her*, *that*, *them*) than the phrasal verbs.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but I believe this question was already addressed at *[Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/is-it-correct-to-change-the-common-structure-in-these-phrasal-verbs)* *[Is there any rule about splitting phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/77472)* and *[Why are prepositions out of place with many phrasal verbs?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113082/)* may also be of interest

Comment: @choster It seems the question is specifically about *it* -- "what's so special about *it* here," kinda.

Comment: @Kris, yes and no. I wasn't asking about *it* specifically. But the examples I could think of, all involved *it*. The suggested posts from choster, brings up a few I didn't think of. I'll add those to figure out if this is the same fundamental issue.