# Why it is not possible to put a noun object after the particle when the object refers to a person with some phrasal verbs ? Is there a specific rule?

Tags: phrasal-verbs, particle-shift

For example:

X pulled off the sweater or X pulled the sweater off

but let someone off the hook not let off the hook someone

to knock over the car or to knock the car over

and to knock the child over but not to knock over the child

X rang someone back but not X rang back someone

Comment: These verbs are called _phrasal verbs_. Do a search on that here (I believe there's a tag, too) and you'll find a lot of relevant questions and answers. This question will most likely end up being closed as a duplicate of one of them eventually, but my current mobile interface is not conducive to advanced searching, so I'll just leave you with the term to search for for now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/)

Comment: My question is very precise. I'm afraid your link doesn't provide much help.

Comment: Actually most of your "not" examples are perfectly fine if not as common.

Answer (score 3):

This is a mixed bag of constructions. Some **are** phrasal verbs, so [particle shift](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/112653/15299) works:

- ***pull*** the sweater **off** ~ ***pull off*** the sweater
- ***knock*** the vase **over** ~ ***knock over*** the vase
- ***knock*** the child **over** ~ ***knock over*** the child
  (this is grammatical but odd --  prototypic uses of *knock over* are with erect objects, not people)

and some are not phrasal verbs, so particle shift **doesn't** work:

- *ring Bill back* ~ **ring back Bill*
- *let Bill back in* ~ **let back Bill in* ~  **let back in Bill*
- *let Bill off the hook* ~ **let off Bill the hook* ~  **let off the hook Bill*