# Which is the correct form?

Tags: clauses

Please **turn off** the fans.

vs.

Please **turn** the fans **off**.

Please explain as well, preferably with examples.

Comment: Answered at [Is it correct to change the common structure in these phrasal verbs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/is-it-correct-to-change-the-common-structure-in-these-phrasal-verbs) (this specific example, in Cool Elf's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are fine as 'turn off' is a *separable* phrasal verb.

The exception is when such a verb is used with the pronoun *it* - you *must* separate apart the verb in that case.

So this would be right:

> Turn it off.

But this would not:

> Turn off it.

Stylistically, you would also generally avoid separating the verb if the noun phrase were very long or convoluted.

That, is rather than saying,

> Turn the newly delivered surround sound television set off.

It would be preferable *stylistically* to say,

> Turn off the newly delivered surround sound television set