# Why does emphasis of "it" allow phrasal verb syntax that would otherwise not be grammatical?

Tags: pronouns, word-order, phrasal-verbs

Edit: the answer cited with the closure doesn't answer the question I posed; it merely reinforces the usual placement of the pronoun.

Consider the phrase **dash it off**.

> I dashed it off without thinking of my tone.

We say:

> I dashed it off.
>
> I dashed an email off.
>
> I dashed off an email.

but we don't say:

> *I dashed off it.

*that is, not unless we give special emphasis to **it***:

> Boss (shaking a printed copy of an email): I'm getting complaints about an email you sent out on Monday, apparently without considering your tone.
>
> Employee: Yes, I dashed off *it* but that was in the morning before I'd had a cup of coffee. After a cup of coffee I was a model employee when it came to writing emails.

**What is it about the emphatic tone used to signify "that one, that particular email you're waving around" that allows word-order usually avoided as unidiomatic?**

Comment: "I dashed off **it**" sounds off. Maybe "I dashed off **that thing** because..."

Comment: You could have a look at this: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80918/is-it-correct-to-change-the-common-structure-in-these-phrasal-verbs

Comment: @YosefBaskin Of course it sounds off but many native speakers of American English (primarily southerners in my experience, and many of them very well-educated) will use that syntax but only in tandem with strong emphasis on **it**.

Comment: @StuartF: That doesn't answer the specific question I posed and makes me think you didn't read my question carefully enough.

Comment: How on earth did this question get linked to ones in which the answers state that pronouns must come directly after the verb with some phrasal verbs, when this question ALREADY STATES IN BLACK AND WHITE THAT THIS IS THE CASE??? Grrrrrr

Comment: I don't think the OP's "example" is remotely credible, so it's not valid to use it to ask ***why*** heavy stress allows for a bit more flexibility with phrasal verbs. A better example would be *I dashed off **that** before I'd really woke up*, which is primarily "licensed" by emphasis on the pronoun ***that***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It may sound totally strange to your ears but I know people who say this sort of thing, and they're literate, well-educated people.  The emphasis (for them) allows **it**  to occur not between verb and particle, and when I hear **it** used with an emphasis that signifies "the specific one you've just mentioned" it doesn't sound so "off" at all to me.  "That one" or "*that* email" is the more normal choice, probably the one I'd make, but that's beside the point.

Comment: What if the employee's retort had been "... I dashed off **it** and several others that morning, truth be told".

Comment: Well, like I said, there's no doubt in my mind that most native speakers would normally say *I dashed that off before I'd really woke up*, but the heavy stress does tend to make the less common version "more natural". But if you know even *one*  "literate, well-educated" person (or even just any true native Anglophone) who would accept your example with ***it***, all I can say is you move in strange circles!

Comment: Well, your own example "I dashed off *that* before I was fully awake" is quite similar. So maybe our circles overlap :-) The emphasis on **it** makes it function very much like **that (one)**.

Comment: I stand by my first comment. I didn't actually vote on the question anyway, but if it gets reopened in its present state I will vote to close on the grounds that the usage you're citing is invalid in the first place. But ***if*** you switch to my example (asking about essentially the same phenomenon), I'll actually ***upvote*** it. Here's the proof that [*I dashed that off in a few minutes*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dashed+that+off+in%22) is far more common than [*I dashed off that in a few minutes.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dashed+off+that+in%22)

Comment: (But the one and only instance of the less common version doesn't give any indication of stress. :)

Comment: But how can you be relying on a text corpus when the phenomenon I'm asking about is in spoken speech? You'd have to be looking at a corpus where vernacular speech patterns are represented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Emphasis* may give a pronoun enough weight to act as one of the heavier noun phrases that support shifting the NP to after the particle.

In a 2017 Language Log post ("[English Verb-Particle Constructions](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=33865)"), Spencer Caplan discusses this very phenomenon. With English verb particles, the order is frequently optional, and Caplan gives two examples:

> 1a) "John picked up the book"
>
> 1b) "John picked the book up"

He then notes an exception (pronouns cannot be thus inverted) and an exception to that exception (unless the pronoun is emphasized via what he calls a *focus reading*):

> 1c) "John put it back"
>
> 1d) *"John put back it" [by default, usually unacceptable]
>
> [we can infer a *focus reading* 1e) "John put back *it*"]

Caplan goes on to discuss what affects a speaker's choice of one order or the other in terms of "acceptability judgments." One factor is "the heaviness of the DP-object,"<sup>1</sup> that is, when the main object is particularly complex or emphasized, it tends to follow the particle (1a); another is "whether or not the object had been recently referred to in context," that is, if the object is familiar, it tends to precede the particle (1b).

Pronouns as a matter of function usually refer to something that came before and are relatively light, so they tend to the pattern of 1b and 1c. In fact, grammarians commonly insist that only 1c is correct for pronouns (see, as an example, Virginia Heidinger in *[Analyzing Syntax and Semantics](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Analyzing_Syntax_and_Semantics/IIs3wjjkk4YC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22In%20the%20second%20sentence%20in%20each%20pair,%20the%20prt%20movt%20transformation%20is%20used,%20and%20in%20the%20second%20set,%20the%20transformation%20is%20obligatory.%22&pg=PA102&printsec=frontcover)*, 1984).  However, these acceptability judgments can shift based on context. If a speaker really wanted to emphasize the pronoun to the point of making *it* heavier, then a speaker's acceptability judgment would support the shift to 1d or 1e in order to show that emphasis:

> John put back *it*.

> Yes, I dashed off *it* [...]

This kind of emphasis is rare, and I cannot recollect encountering such emphasis for *it*. That's one reason why ELL instruction tends not to mention the exceptions, as [this ELL StackExchange answer demonstrates](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/327678/pick-up-phrasal-verb-with-pronouns).

---

For this answer, I did try to find an extant example using *dash off* and *it*, but the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) didn't have anything (the closest it had was "At least he sat down to dash off something"), and Google Books hasn't turned up useful results.

<sup>1</sup>If you want to see more examples of "heavy" noun phrases allowing a shift to after the particle, Wikipedia ("[Heavy NP Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_NP_shift#Heavy_NP_shift_in_English)") gives a decent account.